# Trying to properly substring with String

Tags: c++, microcontroller, sparkcore

Given the following function:

If I execute `setColor("R:0,G:0,B:255,");`

I'm expecting the `red`, `grn`, `blu` values to be:

`0 0 255` except I'm getting `0 0 0`

It's working fine for `R:255,G:0,B:0,` or `R:0,G:255,B:0,` though.

```
int setColor(String command) {

    //Parse the incoming command string
    //Example command R:123,G:100,B:50,
    //RGB values should be between 0 to 255
    int red = getColorValue(command, "R:", "G");
    int grn = getColorValue(command, "G:", "B");
    int blu = getColorValue(command, "B:", ",");

    // Set the color of the entire Neopixel ring.
    uint16_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(red, grn, blu));
    }

    strip.show();

    return 1;
}

int getColorValue(String command, String first, String second) {

    int rgbValue;

    String val = command.substring(command.indexOf(first)+2, command.indexOf(second));
    val.trim();
    rgbValue = val.toInt();

    return rgbValue;
}
```

Comment: What `String` implementation are you using?

Comment: We need to know the details of how the `String` class you are using works to assess the problem. Otherwise we can only guess. Is there any particular reason you aren't using the C++ standard library string implementation? (`std::string`)

Comment: You should pass all strings by reference, or better yet, as const reference.

Comment: @gotnull I suggest you check the documentation for the implementation and check how the indexOf function works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just modifying my code:

```
int setColor(String command) {
    int commaIndex = command.indexOf(',');
    int secondCommaIndex = command.indexOf(',', commaIndex+1);
    int lastCommaIndex = command.lastIndexOf(',');

    String red = command.substring(0, commaIndex);
    String grn = command.substring(commaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
    String blu = command.substring(lastCommaIndex+1);

    // Set the color of the entire Neopixel ring.
    uint16_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(red.toInt(), grn.toInt(), blu.toInt()));
    }

    strip.show();

    return 1;
}
```

I simply just do: `255,0,0` and it works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your `String` implementation, I can only make an educated guess.
What happens is that `indexOf(second)` doesn't give you what you think.

```
"R:0,G:0,B:255,"
    ^    ^- indexOf("B:")
    |- indexOf(",")
```

It works for your other cases as none of the things they look for occur more than once in the string.

Looking at  the SparkCore [Docs](http://docs.spark.io/firmware/#language-syntax-string-class) we find the documentation for both `indexOf` and `substring`.

**indexOf()**
Locates a character or String within another String. By default, searches from the beginning of the String, but can also start from a given index, allowing for the locating of all instances of the character or String.

```
string.indexOf(val)
string.indexOf(val, from)
```

**substring()**

```
string.substring(from)
string.substring(from, to)
```

So now to fix your problem you can use the second variant of `indexOf` and pass that the index you found from your first search.

```
int getColorValue(String command, String first, String second) {

    int rgbValue;
    int beg = command.indexOf(first)+2;
    int end = command.indexOf(second, beg);
    String val = command.substring(beg, end);
    val.trim();
    rgbValue = val.toInt();

return rgbValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, I would split the string using a comma as the delimiter then parse each substring into a key-value pair. You could use a vector of value for the second part if you always have the sequence "R,G,B" in which case why have the "R:", "G:" or "B:" at all?

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that `command.indexOf(second)` will always find you the *first* comma, therefore for `B` the `val` becomes empty string.

Assuming that `indexOf` is something similar to [.Net's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx), maybe try

```
int start = command.indexOf(first)+2;
int end = command.indexOf(second, start)
String val = command.substring(start+2, end);
```

Note the second argument for the second call to `indexOf`, I think it will make `indexOf` to look for matches *after* `start`. I also think you'd better pass a `","` as a `second` for all calls, and add +1 or -1 to `end` to compensate for this passing `","` instead of `"G"` and `"B"`.

Or just use another limiter for `B` part, like `R:0,G:0,B:0.` (dot instead of comma).